# Почему вместо цифр отображается XXX-XX-XX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="wrapper">       
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const phonenumber = (numbers) => {
    let format = "XXX-XX-XX"
    let code = '+7 (903) '
    let operator = ' (Beeline)'
    let timeInfo = 'звоните с 10 до 21'

    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      format = format.replace('x', numbers[i]);
    }

    format.split("").reverse().join("");

    return `${code}${format}${operator}${timeInfo}`;
  }
  phonenumber('1111133')

  $("#wrapper").append(`<div>${phonenumber('1111133')}</div>`);    
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    const phonenumber = (numbers) => {
        let format = "XXX-XX-XX"
        let code = '+7 (903) '
        let operator = ' (Beeline)'
        let timeInfo = 'звоните с 10 до 21'


        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)

        {
            format = format.replace('X', numbers[i]);
        }
       
          format.split("").reverse().join("");


        return `${code}${format}${operator}${timeInfo}`;
      }
    phonenumber('11111337')

    $("#wrapper").append(`<div>${phonenumber('11111337')}</div>`);    
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="wrapper">


</body>
</html>
```

Вы допустили ошибку, в строке

```
format = format.replace('X', numbers[i]);
```

Javascript чувствителен к регистру букв и переменных.

Comment: `.replace(/x/gi, numbers[i])`, теперь не чувствителен.